# Installing package via composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

it gives me an error.
my current dbal version is **^3.0**

> Problem 1
> - lotuashvili/laravel-tbcpay[1.1.0, ..., 1.1.4] require doctrine/dbal ^2.9 -> found doctrine/dbal[v2.9.0, ..., 2.13.x-dev] but
> it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.0).
> - Root composer.json requires lotuashvili/laravel-tbcpay ^1.1 -> satisfiable by lotuashvili/laravel-tbcpay[1.1.0, ..., 1.1.4].
>
> Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades,
> downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific
> versions.

I tried to update all packages

Answer (score 3):

You're simply using incompatible package versions. `lotuashvili/laravel-tbcpay` package requires `doctrine/dbal` 2.9 and up (excluding 3.x), while you require `doctrine/dbal` 3.x.

Since there is no version of `lotuashvili/laravel-tbcpay` that supports `doctrine/dbal` 3.x, your only course of action is to downgrade Doctrine DBAL in your project to 2.9.

Comment: I used "2.9" version before but not worked. then I updated all my packages. still not working.

Comment: Okay. i downgraded and now it is installed. thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2):

`lotuashvili/laravel-tbcpay` requires `doctrine/dbal` v2, your own `composer.json` requires that same package in v3. If you want to use `lotuashvili/laravel-tbcpay` (which hasn't seen any new package since nearly two years!), you should either downgrade DBAL or open a support ticket in their issue tracker

Comment: Okay. i downgraded and now it is installed. thanks for answer.